# IE Ajax response is old data

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, browser-cache

The data displayed in my app is retrieved with ajax requests. I post a form to a script with ajax. This makes changes to the database. On successful post a callback function makes an ajax request for the current page (the same one that posts the form). This page will now have changed due to the changes in the database. (So it's basically an ajax refresh after changes have been made via ajax).

Everything works fine in chrome and FF, the changes are made to the database and the page is refreshed afterwards. But in IE it does not display the new data, even though the changes have been made to the database, and all the callback functions execute.

I can make the changes in IE and when I refresh in chrome and FF I can see the changes, but for the changes to display in IE I have to close and reopen the browser???

What can be causing this?

Comment: Maybe it's catching. Would be nice to have some more informations like which version of IE and how do you make the ajax call. Try to add a GET Parameter to your call with a random number to prevent catching: GET index.php?r=323434

Comment: IE 8, and I use JQuery .load() for the request. I also think it could be caching, I'm going to append a timestamp to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the js reload(true). The argument should force the refresh of the page ignoring the cache.

Have you also tried to add this in your html?

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: Okay, I got it. By appending a timestamp to the ajax request url, the browser cleared the cache and loaded the new content.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: i also have the same problem but i dont understand how you fixed it